# Javascript/JQuery multiple input, get input position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with multiple input with same name. User will be able to add/remove the input line dynamically. eg.

```
<div><select name="Car[]"></select> <input name="Qty[]"></div>
<button> Add another line</button>
```

With user interaction, there's a possibility it will become:

```
<div><select name="Car[]"></select> <input name="Qty[]"></div>
<div><select name="Car[]"></select> <input name="Qty[]"></div>
<div><select name="Car[]"></select> <input name="Qty[]"></div>
.......
<button> Add another line</button>
```

The add button just make a clone of the parent () and append it below.

I want to enforce eg Honda Civic, the only allowed qty is less than 9. Toyota Prius qty is less than 17...

The enforcement will be using on jquery.change() function. **$(input[name="Qty"]).change)**

```
$( input[name="Qty"] ).change(function() {
   if(***value car*** == "Honda Civic" && $(this).val() > 9) $(this).val(0);
   else if(***value car*** == "Toyota Prius" && $(this).val() > 17) $(this).val(0);
   else if(***value car*** == "Maserati Ghibli" && $(this).val() > 3) $(this).val(0); 
});
```

How can I get the input quantity position, and get the value of input car?

Comment: For that you might need to show how your add code works..

Comment: I just use jquery clone.

Comment: Ok then how would you assign qty based on the car type?

Comment: Also, it will be easy if post relevant complete code or create a fiddle for us to work.

Comment: take a look at the edited question.

Comment: can you elaborate more on _How can I get the input quantity position, and get the value of input car?_

Comment: What I mean is, for example, when user is inserting an input on line 3 for Qty, I want to get the value of Car on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create an object which stores car names to limits? For example:

```
var carLimits = {
    'Honda Civic': '8',
    'Toyota Prius': '16'
};
```

You could then just count how many 'things' the user has added.

`hondaCivicCount++`

And then create an if statement to check if the `hondaCivicCount` is less than than, or equal to the `carLimit` before adding a 'thing'.

You'd be best of doing some sort of server-side verification though, if whatever you're doing needs to be secure.

Answer (score -1):

Try Jquery .size() it will tell how much select or input u have https://api.jquery.com/size/.

and get value by using .each() https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I was planning to use jquery $(input[name=Qty]).change() to check while user is typing. But I am open for any other suggestion.

Comment: can share your code ? or if you make fiddle it will best